# HDMI "splitting"/"sharing"

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

My Laptop has only one HDMI-out and I am playing with the idea of buying another external monitor. I found some solutions like USB to HDMI. (Unluckily my laptop has only USB-C 3.2 Gen 1, therefore no display-out)

However, when searching about this topic a question came into my mind:

An HDMI can output 120 hertz. (theoretically up to 240, but currently then output like 120 hertz). Wouldn't it be possible to "share" these 120 hertz?
The splitters normally just duplicate the image, but my idea would be like: 1 frame goes to monitor 1, the second frame goes to monitor 2, then the third frame again to monitor 1 and so on. This would result in 60 hertz for each monitor and thus would be easily enough for a productivity seutp. (Of course not for gaming)

I did not make a lot of research, this question just came into my mind and I am sure someone here knows way more than I would after searching for hours, therefore I would be happy if someone can give me an answer!

Comment: As far as I know, no, you cannot do that with HDMI.  (Displayport MSTS comes close, but that is not HDMI). You howver *can* connect an external display over USB.  There is a distinction between 'laptop generates the image for the display and you have a osrt of adaptor for USB to monitor' and the alternative 'more like an external GPU on the USB bus.  I had one of the latter. Worked but damn slow. Fine to read mail on, not for playing games, watching video, youtube etc.

Comment: One other altertive is an USB dockingstation with build in graphics.

Comment: Yeah sure, i know those alternatives, as mentioned that shouldn't be any problem. However this question came into my mind an really interested me. Would be interesting to research how realistic this ist.